# Is there a way to make the website's main content column wider?

Tags: feature-request, design

Many people have a wider screen that can take advantage of more usable space on the Stack Exchange websites, especially when reading code on Stack Overflow, Super User, etc. Unfortunately, the website layout is very narrow and wastes lots of space on the sides of the page instead of reactively putting that extra space in the center column which takes just a couple CSS attributes to fix.

Is there a user preference somewhere I need to toggle so I can use the full width of my monitor for sites like Stack Overflow? If not, can we get it added as a feature request?

- Note: I know I can, but I don't want to hack-inject the CSS into of the browser in the console for each page.